# Why is the $\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt[3]{5}) $splitting of the polynomial $(x^3 - 5)(x^2 + 1)$ and not just $(x^3 - 5)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, roots-of-unity, splitting-field

I know that $\zeta = \sqrt[3]{5}$ satisfies the polynomial $x^3-5 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$, and splits completely in $\mathbb{Q}(i, \alpha, \zeta)$, where $\alpha = \sqrt{3}$.
I found the roots $x_1 = \zeta$, $x_2 = \zeta/2 + \zeta i \alpha /2$ and $x_3 = \zeta/2 - \zeta i \alpha /2$

And I can write $\zeta = x_1$, $\alpha = (2x_1/x_2 - 1)^4/3$ and $i = (x_3-x_2)/(x_1\alpha)$, and since the polynomial $(x^3-5)$ already splits completely over $\mathbb{Q}(i, \alpha, \zeta)$, why do I need the extra term $(x^2+1)$?

Comment: $i$ isn't in the splitting field of $x^3-5$.

Comment: Why not? I could write it as $i = (x_3-x_2)/(x_1\alpha)$, doesn't that mean that it is in the splitting field?

Comment: @Ponky $\alpha$ isn't in the splitting field of $x^3-5$, so no.

Comment: @Arthur But I can also write the $\alpha$ in terms of the roots $x_1, x_2, x_3$

Comment: @Ponky You can't write $\alpha$ in terms of the roots.  $$\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{2x_1}{x_2} - 1\right)^4 = \frac{1}{3}\alpha^4 = 3 \neq \sqrt{3}$$

Comment: @Ponky No, really you can't. The Galois group of $K+\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]5,\sqrt{-3})$ is $S_3$, so by the Galois correspondence, $K$ only has one quadratic subfield $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-3})$. Therefore $i\notin K$ and $\sqrt3\notin K$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The splitting field of $x^3-5$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}, i\sqrt{3})$.  In particular, $i,\sqrt{3} \not\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}, i\sqrt{3}),$ which becomes apparent if you realize $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}, i\sqrt{3})$ as a $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5})$-vector space with basis $\{1, i\sqrt{3}\}$ (along with the provable fact $\sqrt{3} \not\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5})$)

Answer (score 2):

To find the splitting field of $x^3-5$ on $\mathbb{Q}$ you have to extend $\mathbb{Q}$ with the root of the polynomial. So the first extension is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5})$ then the other two roots of the polinomial, $\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{5}, \frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{5}$, aren't in this extension, infact there isn't complex number in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5})$. So now let's extend with another roots, like $\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{5}$, and we obtein $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}, \frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{5})$ but $\frac{\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{5},}{\frac{\sqrt[3]{5}}{2}}=-1+i\sqrt{3}$, so $i\sqrt{3} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}, i\sqrt[3]{5}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt[3]{5},)$. Then we can conclude that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}, \frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{5})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}, i\sqrt{3})$ and this is the the splitting field of $x^3-5$. But $i, \sqrt{3} \not \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}, i\sqrt{3})$.

If we consider the splitting field of $(x^3-5)(x^2+1)$ we nead to extend $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}, i\sqrt{3})$ with a root of $x^2+1$ and we obtain $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}, i\sqrt{3}, i)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}, \sqrt{3}, i)$. So how it's easly to check the splitting field of $(x^3-5)(x^2+1)$ contains the splitting field of $(x^3-5)$.

Comment: yes i'm so sorry, I was in a hurry and I got confused. Now i think it's correct. @PaceNielsen

Answer (score 1):

The splitting field of $x^3-5$ has degree at most $3!=6$.

$\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt[3]{5})$ contains $\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt{3})$, which has degree $4$, and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5})$, which has degree $3$. Therefore, $\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt[3]{5})$ has degree a multiple of $12$, and so cannot be at most $6$.